# Bootstrap drop down list goes under the nav bar

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

Here is how it looks like when the drop-down menu appears.
[image]

**Nav-bar :**

```
     <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">

                                <div class="navbar-header">
                                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
                                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                    </button>
                                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Categories</a>
...
```

**Drop-down:**

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">

            <li>
               <div class="panel panel-default">
                 <div class="panel-body">
                  <div class="panel-info">
                    <p><strong>Black Dress</strong></p>
                      <p>Each Price :&nbsp;<strong>Rs. 500.00</strong></p>
                      <p>Quantity :&nbsp; <input type="number" value="3"/> 
                    <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span></p>
                                   ....
```

Tried with positioning(`position:relative`).But couldn't get the required result. (Drop-down over the `nav-bar`) .Thanks in advance.

Here is an example of [my work](https://jsfiddle.net/nmyx4xqn/embedded/result/).

Comment: You have to use `z-index`.

Comment: @alirezasafian I used. But Nothing changed. Here is how I used it . `.dropdown {
    z-index: 1010; 
}`

Comment: .dropdown-menu {z-index:99999;}

Comment: Please, post your completed code or provide a demo.

Comment: @yjs . I tried. But still the same result .

Comment: @alirezasafian I have attached a sample code . Please check it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why the given `z-index` doesn't work?

`.dropdown-menu` is not in the same level of `.navbar` so give `z-index:1010;` and `position:relative;` to the `#header`(its parent).

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/alireza_safian/nmyx4xqn/1/)

Comment: Thank you so much.. It works fine. Unfortunately I can't up-vote your answer. :(

Comment: It's okay. Good luck.